# Selecting column with opposite value of one given

Tags: mysql

I have two columns `column_a(INT)` and `column_b(INT)`. I want to do a select query that gives me the value in the column that does not contain the value I give.
For example:

```
column_a| column_b
   5    |    10
```

If I were to `SELECT (something over here) FROM TABLE WHERE column_a = 10 OR column_b = 10;`
The result should push out **5** (value in `column_a`.

Is this even possible?

Note: The value of **10** could be in either columns. So lets say if **10** was in `column_a` and **5** in `column_b`, the above query should still give me **5** but it would be retrieved from `column_b` instead of `column_a`

Note 2: Both columns will never contain the same value.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand this. Please explain clearly.

Comment: @1000111 I think he just wants to select the value in a row which does not match a given value.

Comment: Okay. But what if both the columns contain the same value provided? @TimBiegeleisen

Comment: I defaulted to returning either of the columns.  Maybe this edge case does matter for the OP.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen got it actually. I will never have a case where both values are the same so I do not need to check for that. I maybe should have included that in my note.

also thanks 1000111 for taking the time to help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your contrived example, you could use a `CASE` statement to attempt to select the value from the two columns which does not match:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN column_a = 10 THEN column_b ELSE column_a END
FROM yourTable
WHERE column_a = 10 OR column_b = 10    -- this might be optional
```

Comment: That did it sir. I wanted to generalize the example. I never knew about this but it is very handy. I will read more up on it.